# Passing a filepath to method using constructor

Tags: c#, xml, file

I am very new in C# & .NET, so I faced some difficulties with passing non-directly path.

I have two methods to work with XML files (adding and reading data) and there I pass a path for my file directly as argument (@"D:\GIT\learning\DAL\Users.xml").
How can I pass it using a `Constructor`?

```
class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        public void ReadData() 
        { 
            List<User> usersList = new List<User>();
            Console.WriteLine("Name-Surname-Age");
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(@"D:\GIT\learning\DAL\Users.xml");
            XmlElement xnode = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;

            XmlElement elementUser = xmlDocument.CreateElement("user");

            XmlElement elementName = xmlDocument.CreateElement("name");
            XmlElement elementSurname = xmlDocument.CreateElement("surname");
            XmlElement elementAge = xmlDocument.CreateElement("age");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
            string name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter surname");
            string surname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter age");
            string age = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            XmlText nameText = xmlDocument.CreateTextNode(name);
            XmlText surnameText = xmlDocument.CreateTextNode(surname);
            XmlText ageText = xmlDocument.CreateTextNode(age);

            elementName.AppendChild(nameText);
            elementSurname.AppendChild(surnameText);
            elementAge.AppendChild(ageText);

            elementUser.AppendChild(elementName);
            elementUser.AppendChild(elementSurname);
            elementUser.AppendChild(elementAge);

            xmlDocument.Save(@"D:\GIT\learning\DAL\Users.xml");
        }

        public void PrintData(User userData)
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(@"D:\GIT\learning\DAL\Users.xml");
            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            XmlElement xRoot = xml.DocumentElement;
            foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
            {
                User user = new User();

                foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (childnode.Name.Equals("name"))
                        user.Name = childnode.InnerText;
                    if (childnode.Name.Equals("surname"))
                        user.Surname = childnode.InnerText;
                    if (childnode.Name.Equals("age"))
                        user.Age = childnode.InnerText;
                }
            }
            foreach (User u in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {u.Name}, Surname: {u.Surname}, Age: {u.Age}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean: passing path to constructor of class UserRepository  and then using it in your method right?

Comment: Yeah, that's  right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only relevant bits left for clarity

```
class UserRepository : IUserRepository {
   private string _path="";
   public UserRepository (string path){
       _path=path;
   }
}
```

pass _path as a paramter to xmlDocument.Load, in both methods eg:

replace

```
xmlDocument.Load(@"D:\GIT\learning\DAL\Users.xml");
```

in both methods with

```
xmlDocument.Load(_path);
```

Comment: I can see it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Example code:

```
  class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
       private string XmlFilePath;

       public UserRepository(string xmlFilePath)
       {
           XmlFilePath = xmlFilePath;
       }

       public void ReadData(string filePath) 
       { 
           xmlDocument.Load(filePath);
       }
    }
```

Here you have a private field in your class that get's initialized inside the constructor.
The value is getting set when creating a new object from your class `UserRepository`.